# Integrated Security Success on Master, Fails on Other Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, authentication, logins

I'm a bit perplexed as to why my connection string is selectively succeeding on the `master` database in SQL Server 2005. Here are the details of my app. Any ideas where to look? I'm clearly missing something. Also keep in mind that the IIS Server and SQL Server are on different machines within an Intranet environment where I am attempting to implement Windows Authentication. Thanks. :)

**Connection strings**:

`Server=SQLServer;Database=master;Integrated Security=true` --**succeeds**
`Server=SQLServer;Database=other;Integrated Security=true` --**fails**

**Fail Error Message**:

`Cannot open database "other" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\IIS_SERVERNAME$'.`

**My IIS Server App Pool and Authentication settings**:

- AppPool: .NET 4.0; Integrated Pipeline; Identity=Network Service
- Authentication: Impersonation=Disabled; Windows Auth=Enabled; Kernel-mode=Enabled; Providers=Negotiate,NTLM

**Update**: Clearly there is a Login of some sort for the machine connecting to my SQL Server with the Integrated Security, otherwise it wouldn't succeed in connecting to the `master` database right? I would guess that to mean there's an issue at the database level, but I cannot figure out which `user` account would give it access to `master` because there are only a handful of users for it.

Comment: have you gone through this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **SQL Server**, as long as a **LOGIN** is valid, it will have access to the master database in a `public` role.  This is both for historical and practical reasons.  For example, stored procedures beginning with "sp_" are searched first in the master database and will execute from there.  The implication is that users need to first have access to the master database to begin with.  **tempdb** is another database that allows user access via the public role.

User databases do not have this as a default setup, so unless the Login is specifically given permission, or has server-wide roles such as "sysadmin", it will not be able to switch to the database context, hence your error.

---

The fact that you manage to log in at all using the machine account means that it is either explicitly a created LOGIN, or is a member of a group that appears under "Logins" when you browse the Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
[SERVER\Instance]
    Security
        Logins
             .... here ....
```

You can specifically assign roles or grant execute permissions to the machine account:

```
use other;
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [DOMAIN\IIS_SERVERNAME$]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_myproc TO [DOMAIN\IIS_SERVERNAME$]
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to see here is the $ in the username, it means it's trying to use local system (or network service account) from the IIS machine to make the connection, instead of a domain user. Btw, are you using domain users and computers?

Please see this MSDN forum question: [Login page error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/8a8d8711-e22b-4eb8-934b-23780c7dd97e/).
You should be able to change the user used for the site in the site properties in IIS.